# How do I explicitely initialize the copy constructor for a class that inherits from std::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Consider the following test code:

```
#include <memory>

class C : public std::enable_shared_from_this<C>
{
    public:
    C(C const& c){}
};

int main()
{

}
```

[Compiling this](https://godbolt.org/z/Gva9Y9oGK) with `-Wextra` will generate the following warning

> warning: base class 'class std::enable_shared_from_this' should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor [-Wextra]

How do I do this correctly? Is there anything that I could trip over in more complicated classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly initialize it by calling its default constructor like this:

```
C(C const& c) : enable_shared_from_this() {}
```

You can also do it by calling its copy constructor like this:

```
C(C const& c) : enable_shared_from_this(c) {}
```

The copy constructor actually does the same thing as the default constructor (it marks the current object as not being owned by a `shared_ptr`) This ensures that the following will do the sensible thing:

```
C(C const& c) = default;  // also calls the copy constructor of the enable_shared_from_this base
```

When an object is copied, you get a new object, so, obviously, it's not owned by the same `shared_ptr` that the other object is.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the explanation!